# Not Getting Revenue Data After Doing All Set-ups For GA4 with website and GTM

Tags: google-analytics, tags, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have started to get data of my site via GA4 and I am able to no. of users, audience activity, acquisition, event value but not getting right conversion number and revenue amount. I have used GTM tags and all tag are going to fire when I am testing but the problem is conversion is going to firing 17 times at once test and purchase tag is going to fire and debugging section we are able to see revenue but on a main dashboard we are not getting data of revenue.

I have done all set up per GA4 with my website, GTM. All events are going to fire but can't able to see revenue or Conversion in my GA4.
I have applied all which is given in :
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtag#purchase

Comment: I voted to close this question because is about debugging a problem but has no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I tried everything too but still he total revenue is 0 and the Monetization screen not showing data.